# Comparing bigram words of a text with input file words

Tags: scala, text, apache-spark

I want to extract special bigrams `(not , word2)` in every document and replace these two words with one number `(1)` if word2 exist in (words.txt) file else it shouldn't be replaced.

here is my data (data.txt):

```
fit perfectly clie . purchased not instructions install helpful . improvement battery life not hoped .

product returned not fit nor solve problem ordered . company honest credited account .

cable good not work . cable extremely hot not recognize devices .
...
```

and (words.txt) file:

```
hoped
instructions
work
fit
...
```

i've tried :

```
   import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext} 

   object test {

   def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val conf1 = new SparkConf().setAppName("test").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf1)
    val searchList = sc.textFile("data/words.txt")
    val searchBigram = searchList.map(word => ("not", word)).collect.toSet
    val sample1 = sc.textFile("data/data.txt")
    val sample2 = sample1.map(s => s.split( """\.""") // split on .
      .map(_.split(" ") // split on space
      .sliding(2) // take continuous pairs
      .map { case Array(a, b) => (a, b)}
      ).map(elem => if (searchBigram.contains(elem)) ("1", "1") else elem)
      .map { case (e1, e2) => e1}.mkString(" "))
    sample2.foreach(println)
     }
    }
```

expected output is :

```
fit perfectly clie . purchased 1 install helpful . improvement battery life 1 .

product returned 1 nor solve problem ordered . company honest credited account .

cable good 1 . cable extremely hot 1 devices . 
...
```

my above code is not complete and it doesn't work, Can anybody help me?

Comment: I think you are trying to write too much code all at once. The resulting code is difficult to read and difficult to debug. Try breaking it up into individual functions. Write and test the individual functions one at a time. Then try to put them together to solve the entire problem.

Comment: Here is a correct version of findNot: `def findNot(word: String): Boolean = word == "not"`. You don't need `return`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick to the bigram approach, I think it would work better if we would make bigrams out of the search items as well.

```
val searchList  = sc.textFile("input_file")
// let's make this also into bigrams and collect as a set
// making the assumption that this list is relatively small and fit in memory
val searchBigram = searchList.map(word => ("not", word)).collect.toSet
```

Now, departing from the result of '.sliding(2)', we can transform the arrays to tuples:

```
val sample = "improvement battery life not hoped".split
// bigrams is an iterator of (improvement,battery), (battery,life), (life,not), (not,hoped)
val bigrams = sample.sliding(2).map{case Array(e1,e2) => (e1,e2)}

//Now we use our bigram search set to find/replace the matching bigrams
// -> (improvement,battery), (battery,life), (life,not), (1,1)
val replaced = bigrams.map(elem => if (searchBigram.contains(elem)) ("1", "1") else elem)

// We undo the tuples to obtain the modified string
val  result = replaced.map{case (e1,e2) => e1}.mkString(" ")
// result:String = improvement battery life 1
```

Integrate that idea in the larger program and that should result in a working process.

Comment: Thank you @maasg for your reply , if i want to read my data file into RDD how can i do this? for example instead of ( val sample = ""improvement battery life not hoped".split") read my data file into RDD, and after that i have 2 RDDs , is it possible?

Comment: You would read that data just like in the example provided on the question: 
    `val rdd = sc.textFile("data/aaa.txt")`

Comment: In this state because of my input data file contains a lot of documents and i want to replace this (not,word2) pattern in every document , in your code instead of sample be a sentence , sample is an input file contain a lot of documents.